# file in content not changing even though I have mount my current working directory as a volume

Tags: node.js, docker

I am running a docker container with the following command:

```
docker-compose run -v $(pwd):/src container_name /bin/bash
```

I have mounted my current worker drive to allow changes made in the container to take effect in the container.

This is not working, and i have to rebuild my images whenver i make the change.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]: what host environment and what kind of Docker are you using, what is your base image, how are you validating that changes are being propagated (or not)?  Is rebuilding the image a significant roadblock?

Comment: Which image are you using?